# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when executing query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am getting an error when running the following code:

```
string SqlQuery = "Update " + frmmain.CityName + " set  assignedtouserid='" + 
frmmain.UserName + "', flag=1 where flag=0 and city like '%" + 
newcituname + "%' ";
LeptonDataLayer.ExecuteNoneQuery(1, SqlQuery);
```

This is the error I'm recieving:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What can i do to resolve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Also: This is scary-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

`frmmain` or one of its fields are null (has not been assigned a `new` object) or `LeptonDataLayer` is null.

You need to figure out which one is null (use a debugger to find this out) and then make sure it has an appropriate value.  Or don't run your query at all.

Also, I have to point out that generally building up `T-SQL` in code is a bad idea because it leaves you very vulnerable to Sql Injection attacks.  You should be calling Stored Procedures and passing in Sql Parameters instead.

Comment: Building up T-SQL in code can be okay. Including user-provided data in those queries is bad.